# Get the five most recent page visits from another database

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I'm writing a query which should give me id, name and city, and the five last visited pages. The id, name and city come from table1, and the five last visited pages from table2.

What I have right now is:

```
SELECT 
id AS `ID`, 
name AS `Company Name`, 
city AS `City`, 
(
    SELECT table2.pagePath
    FROM table2
    WHERE table2.visitdate = 
        (
            SELECT MAX(table2.visitdate)
            FROM table2
        )
)

FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2
ON table1.id = table2.id
WHERE zip_code = "1111 AB"
GROUP BY table1.id;
```

As you might notice, it doesn't work...

I'm trying to use the subquery to get the most recent visited page, as the first of five. I'm getting a response, which is the same page path for all returned rows.

Anyone who can push me to the right direction?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
select t.*, t2.*
from table1 t1 left join
     (select t2.*,
             row_number() over (partition by t2.id order by t2.visitdate desc) as seqnum
      from table2 t2
     ) t2
     on t2.id = t1.idand t2.seqnum <= 5;
```

Note that your query seems to have logic not described in your question.  I have focused on the query that you asked, not on the query which doesn't seem to have much relationship to the question.